# Update WTL To WTL 10: 'AtlCopyBitmap': identifier not found

Tags: visual-c++, wtl

I upgrade a vc++ solution from WTL80 to WTL100 now I get the following error:

error C3861: 'AtlCopyBitmap': identifier not found

WTL100 is from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/files/WTL%2010/)

It seams AtlCopyBitmap was moved, renamed or delete. But I do not find any hind what to use instead.

My usage is

```
inline HBITMAP CloneBitmap( HBITMAP hbmSrc, bool bAsBitmap = false )
{
  CBitmapHandle bmSrc( hbmSrc );
  SIZE sizeDst;
  if ( bmSrc.GetSize( sizeDst ) )
        return AtlCopyBitmap( hbmSrc, sizeDst, bAsBitmap );   
  return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a replacement. Seems like the code was cleaned up for WTL10 and this function simply was removed.

You can get the code of `AtlCopyBitmap()` from WTL 9.1: [atlgdi.h](https://sourceforge.net/p/wtl/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/wtl/Include/atlgdi.h) (from line 3762)